# Connect two monitors to two HDTVs

Tags: networking, multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv

Good day to all,

I would like to request for some help here. Let me say sorry in advance for the broken English. I have a pc connected to two monitors. Let's call them Monitor A and Monitor B. What I want to do now is to connect both monitors to two HDTVs. Let's call them TV A and TV B. The length from the monitors to the TVs is about 40 meters (130 feet). I would like to mirror the display of Monitor A to TV A and Monitor B to TV B. My question is, can I use 2 HDMI extenders with cat6 cables connected from HDMI ports Monitor A & B to TV A & B? Your kind help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your monitors likely only have HDMI inputs, not outputs. HDMI ports are one or the other, not both.

In order to get the effect you want, you'll either need a video card that can output to all of your monitors and TVs simultaneously, duplicating the displays you want, or you need HDMI duplicators.

> Hemi Splitter 1 in 2 out - ability to distribute Audio and video signal from a single source to 2 HDMI displays simultaneously

[https://www.amazon.com/HDS-102-Splitter-Certified-Duplicate-Resolutions/dp/B00F5R9TNM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00F5R9TNM)
(Random link for example of device only, not shopping or brand advice.)